# Deploy in SharePoint without downtime

Tags: sharepoint

We have wsps in our project.But whenever wsp is deployed the "Service Unavailable" page comes at the site level.
Is there any way that few Dlls can be added in GAC without taking a downtime in production server?

Answer (score 0):

No is the answer in reality. When you do a deployment with a WSP the reset is triggered so the latest dll's are reloaded and to clear down memory within the application pools.

So anything that is related to server side code will require a reset.

If you update anything in the hive you can get away with zero downtime deployment.

There is a more in depth answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83049/when-do-we-need-an-iisreset-after-deployment) as to when do you need an IISReset

Cheers
Truez

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to do a local deployment and stage this yourself.  Install-SPSolution offers the local switch.  You could in theory use this and control the rotation of the deployment (assuming more than one server).  but as noted above to get IIS to reload the assemblies requires the application pool to be cycled.  Assemblies are loaded from GAC, but are then memory resident.

https://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2012/07/16/deploying-sharepoint-wsp-solutions-without-downtime/

I've tried it a few times and not been hugely successful so your mileage may vary.

If you are dependent on GACed Assemblies you can technically push them yourself outside of the WSP.  However you may end up in a weird place as the following may occur:
1) You retract the web application from all servers (this will also retract the solution).  You may end up with nothing or orphaned assemblies in GAC
2) You add a server later on and it takes the deployment package and you have a server with a different set of bits in your farm.  This is painful to troubleshoot for anyone.  Imagine if you left?
3) You deploy an assembly and it has a different version than what your web.config expects and it can't be used or found.